# Binary expansion

Tags: number-theory

> The ternary expansion $x = 0.10101010\ldots$ is given. Give the binary expansion of $x$. Alternatively, transform the binary expansion $y = 0.110110110\ldots$ into a ternary expansion.

By the ternary expansion, do they mean $0.10101010\ldots_3$? Otherwise it just seems like we need to find the binary expansion of $0.10101010\ldots.$

Comment: Yes, they mean that $0.10101010\ldots$ is the ternary expansion of $x$. You’re expected to evaluate $x$ in more usual terms and then determine its binary expansion (which will be very simple).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I am confused what saying "The ternary expansion $x$" has to do with anything. Also, what is a ternary expansion?

Comment: Read it as: The ternary expansion of the real number $x$ is $0.10101010\ldots_{\text{three}}$. What is the binary expansion of $x$?

Comment: They are saying that $x= 1\cdot(3)^{-1}+0\cdot (3)^{-2}+1\cdot (3)^{-3}+0\cdot (3)^{-4}+\dots$.  One does not need to write a subscript after a number to signify what base it is in if it is understood by context.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott How do we find the binary expansion? We know that $x = \frac{8}{27}$.

Comment: @user19405892: Have you evaluated $x$ in more familiar terms yet? Note that $9x=10.101010\ldots_{\text{three}}=10_{\text{three}}+x$; can you solve for $x$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes, but how do we get it in base 2?

Comment: @user19405892: I wouldn’t bother with any special method: it’s pretty easy to express $\frac38$ as a sum of (negative) powers of $2$ just by inspection.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I get $0.011_2$ as the answer?

Comment: @user19405892: That’s right: $\frac14+\frac18$, or $0.011$ in binary.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Why do they call it an expansion if it is really a representation?

Comment: @user19405892: It’s both: that’s simply one of the meanings of *expansion*. I imagine that the original motivation for the use of the term in this way is that in general a real number ‘expands’ into an infinite series of terms of the form $db^k$ when we write it in base $b$ (where $d$ is one of the digits $0,1,\ldots,b-1$).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott How would we transform the binary expansion $y = 0.110110110\ldots$ into a ternary expansion?

Comment: @user19405892: In that problem you’re really asking how to find the ternary expansion of $\frac67$. That’s a moderately messy problem that should really be a separate question.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I just added it to the question. Can you answer it now?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

In *decimal* if a number repeats with periodicity one after the decimal point, it can be achieved via division by nine by the repeated number.

E.g. $\frac{2}{9}=0.222222222\dots$

$\frac{5}{9}=0.555555555\dots$

If it has periodicity two, it can be accomplished via division by $99$

$\frac{13}{99}=0.1313131313\dots$

$\frac{57}{99}=0.5757575757\dots$

If it has periodicity longer than that, use more nines...

---

What is special about nine in this pattern?

> It is one less than ten.

How might this pattern extend to other number bases?

> Dividing by the number one less than the base has a similar pattern.  E.g. $\frac{3}{4}=0.3333333\dots$ in base five.  Similarly $\frac{42}{77}=0.42424242\dots$ in base eight (*octal*).  (That is specifically $42_8$ divided by $77_8$, i.e. $\frac{34}{63}$ in decimal.)

---

For your number, $0.10101010\dots_3$ what might it be if expressed as a fraction?

> $\frac{10}{22}$ with both $10$ and $22$ in base $3$., i.e. $\frac{1\cdot 3+0}{2\cdot 3+2} = \frac{3}{8}$ in decimal.

Comment: Simple but amazed feature you presented but our normal people did not realize.